# Error appearing after moving to a new server

Tags: magento-1.8

we moved to a new server and the tech guys installed it properly but there are errors appeared only on the homepage, nothing else is displayed. Is there a solution for this?! Thank you.

> Deprecated: iconv_set_encoding(): Use of iconv.internal_encoding is
>   deprecated in
>   /home/b2zee/public_html/b2c/lib/Zend/Validate/Hostname.php on line 521
>
> Deprecated: iconv_set_encoding(): Use of iconv.internal_encoding is
>   deprecated in
>   /home/b2zee/public_html/b2c/lib/Zend/Validate/Hostname.php on line 617

Comment: **Welcome to Magento StackExchange!** This type of question is an issue with an incompatibility of the version of PHP on your web server and the version that your Magento codebase supports. Could you share the version of PHP you're running on your new server?

Comment: Hello Robbie! Thanks for replying that fast. I asked the server and they said that they are using this PHP version 
root@d70 [~]# php -v
PHP 5.6.22 (cli) (built: Jun 2 2016 09:01:37)

Comment: Also on the old server it was 5.6.22

Answer (score 2):

Dear your server using PHP 5.6 this error has only come if your server is using PHP 5.6 and Magento officially mention if you use PHP 5.6 you need to use this patch

[Patch of php 5.6](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/renttek/29beaaa1e90909639501/raw/be5df0b33b72cdc2ab037d374802c53ccba066df/0001-BUGIFX-Magento-Zend-Framework-1-PHP5.6.patch)

I would suggest using your previous server php version, or if you don't know then just change current php server.

Comment: Hello Naveed, thank you so much. I suggested this on the server technical guys and they said that they have those versions > 5.3.29
> 5.4.45
> 5.5.36 what do you suggest?

Comment: give a try 5.5.36

Comment: How about using your patch? Would that be better?

Comment: this patch from magneto not from me :), I am afraid if you are very basic in tech, but if give a try to patch please have a backup before applying patch. so you can rollback your source.

Comment: Thank you, I am sending this to the online server and they take care of it. So if anything goes wrong they are responsible, I told them from the beginning that I am not an expert in this, still they said that they don't know what are those errors. Thank you Naveed I'll try this.

Comment: best of luck...

Comment: I just checked that we were using PHP 5.6.22 on the old server, so downgrading will still be helpful? I think the patch would be fine, right?

Comment: yes give it a try

Comment: The patch didn't work, I feel hopeless.

Comment: Do you think Downgrading will make it work? Although on the old server I am using PHP 5.6

Comment: Dear as far I understand from your error iconv_set_encoding() is use in your code and it is deprecated in 5.6 and you said in previous server you were using 5.6.22 so from 5.6 onware they remove deprecation check from iconv_set_encoding() even in php 7 you can use iconv_set_encoding(). here is [manual]( http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-set-encoding.php)

So in short please downgrade your module if your server provider not supporting upgrade version from 5.6 so, 80% chances are your problem will solved.

Comment: Thank you so much Naveed! It worked and the errors are not appearing, but now the other issue is that the website is not fully loading, please check it here www.b2zee.com/b2c/

Comment: We fixed it, it was just wrong permissions for the files, that's why it was not fully loading. THANK YOU SO MUCH NAVEED for your Answer! I would really appreciate it if you could provide a way of communication to connect to you later in case if I want any advice. I can support you in anything else too. Thanks again.